# What are the functional group names of halogenoalkanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, halides

The functional group name of other organic compounds is easily findable, but that of the halogenoalkanes *(or haloalkanes)* is not. This makes me wonder if such a name exists for the halogenoalkanes or if they are an exception.

Are there such names? If yes, what are they for the different possible halogens present in a given compound?

Clarification: With functional group name I mean hydroxyl for the alcohols, phenyl for arenes, etc..

Answer (score 1):

They don't have a functional group name similar to that of hydroxyl/phenyl/etc. Instead, you've to name them as if they were an alkyl branch - "haloalkyl" - and that too within parentheses.

---

Have a look at this simple comparison:

[image: three derivatives of propanedioic acid - at locant 2]

Notice that both 2,3-dimethylbutyl and chloromethyl are both within parentheses, whereas phenyl isn't. Therefore don't mistake "haloalkyl" to be a *short name* as "phenyl" is. There simply is no such *short name*, and you've to name it as an alkyl chain instead.